# have problems in Linking multiple JComboBox in JTable one time

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I got a quite tricky problem when I do some code on JTable

I need to add one line In JTable when I click "Add" button, and I want one of the columns to render 
as a JComboBox

the problem is that when I only add one line, it works fine. 
but when I add multiple lines a time, no matter which combobox I choose item from, It will always trigger the last comboBox's event(seems always the same combobox since I have printed the hashcode of jComboBox in MyComboxActionListener class. it's the same).

why is that happens , I can't figure it out. Since It's totally a new comboBox and a new listener when I add one line.

Following is the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    ProducedProcedure_new addedProducedProcedure = new ProducedProcedure_new();    // the new item 
    componentProcedureTableModel.getWorks().add(addedProducedProcedure);        //add one line to the table
    componentProcedureTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(componentProcedureTableModel.getRowCount()-1, componentProcedureTableModel.getRowCount()-1);   

    jTable1.changeSelection(componentProcedureTableModel.getRowCount()-1,0, false, false);

    List<String> procedureNames = produceCardManager.getProcedureNames(componentIdTextField.getText().trim(),false);    //get the items added to combobox
    renderColumnAsCombox(1,procedureNames,addedProducedProcedure);   //-------------------------------------------
}        

 void renderColumnAsCombox(int columnIndex , List<String> items,ProducedProcedure_new producedProcedure) {
    TableColumn col = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

    for(String item : items) {
       comboBox.addItem(item);
    }
    MyComboxActionListener myComboxActionListener = new MyComboxActionListener(columnIndex,comboBox,producedProcedure);
    comboBox.addActionListener(myComboxActionListener);
    col.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
}     

class MyComboxActionListener implements ActionListener {  // listen for the select event of the combobox
    private JComboBox jComboBox;
    private ProducedProcedure_new producedProcedure;
    private int columnIndex;

    public MyComboxActionListener(int columnIndex,JComboBox jComboBox,ProducedProcedure_new producedProcedure) {
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        this.jComboBox = jComboBox;
        this.producedProcedure = producedProcedure;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          String selectedItem = (String)jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
          producedProcedure.getProcedure().setProcedureName(selectedItem);
          producedProcedure.getProcedure().setProcedureId(String.valueOf(produceCardManager.getProcedureId(selectedItem)));
          producedProcedure.getProcedure().setFactor(produceCardManager.getProcedureFactor(selectedItem));   //automately update the factor
          ((ComponentProcedureTableModel_new)jTable1.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), may be you should use ` TableModelListener` when the cell is edited.. and there handle the events from diferent cells [row,column]

Comment: I don't think you so much have a problem, but you misunderstand how `JTable` works. Check out [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I don't think I can use a TableModelListener since I need to listen to the event of each comboBox.

Comment: `"I don't think I can use a TableModelListener since I need to listen to the event of each comboBox."` -- yep, you don't understand how JTables work. Please read the tutorial to see how wrong this is.